# I am getting error when I compile this code

Tags: equations, align

### Problem Description

What is the problem in this code? I am getting an error. Please help me.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{equation}
\begin{align*}
 \lambda&=\dfrac{Gr_{x}}{R_{e}^2}   &   \widetilde{N}&=\dfrac{Gr_{x}^{\ast}}{Gr_{x}} \\[3ex]
 Gr_{x}&=\dfrac{g\beta_{T}\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)x^{3}}{\nu^{2}}       &   Gr_{x}^{\ast}&=\dfrac{g\beta_{C}\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)x^{3}}{\nu^{2}}\\[3ex]
 M^{2}&=\dfrac{\sigma\,B_{0}^{2}}{a\,\rho\, x^{n-1}}   &   Nr&=\dfrac{16\sigma^{\ast}}{3k^{\ast}}\,\dfrac{T^{3}_{\infty}}{k_{2}} \\[3ex]
 \dfrac{1}{Pr}&=\dfrac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}       &   A&=\dfrac{b}{a}\\[3ex]
S_{c}&=\dfrac{\nu}{D_{B}}   &   \dfrac{1}{k_{1}}&=\dfrac{\mu \phi}{k'}\\[3ex]
 S_{r}&=\dfrac{D_{m}\,k_{T}\,\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)}{\alpha_{m}\,C_{p}\,C_{s}\,\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)}      &   D_{f}&=\dfrac{D_{m}\,k_{T}\,\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)}{\alpha_{m}\,C_{p}\,C_{s}\,\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)}
\end{align*} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put `align*` inside `equation`, since `align*` is already a top-level display environment. The error message is pretty clear. Just remove the outer `equation` environment.

Comment: No, It's different. Please help me.

Comment: I can't show you the answer because I don't know what the question is. You are asking "_What is the problem in this code?_", and the linked answer explains that. Clearly you are trying to get a particular numbering but you don't say which one: One number for the whole block? Aligned where? Top, middle, bottom? How am I supposed to know what you want?

Comment: One number for whole set of equation. Aligned in Middle.

Comment: @DIalfrost No, There are multiple equation numbers.

Comment: To have only one equation number vertically centered, use the `aligned` environment instead of `align*` within the `equation` environment.

Comment: @Math-Man Does this solve your problem? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kahzr.png Or do you want 2 equations on 1 line

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{align}
 \lambda&=\dfrac{Gr_{x}}{R_{e}^2}   &   \widetilde{N}&=\dfrac{Gr_{x}^{\ast}}{Gr_{x}} \\[3ex]
 Gr_{x}&=\dfrac{g\beta_{T}\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)x^{3}}{\nu^{2}}       &   Gr_{x}^{\ast}&=\dfrac{g\beta_{C}\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)x^{3}}{\nu^{2}}\\[3ex]
 M^{2}&=\dfrac{\sigma\,B_{0}^{2}}{a\,\rho\, x^{n-1}}   &   Nr&=\dfrac{16\sigma^{\ast}}{3k^{\ast}}\,\dfrac{T^{3}_{\infty}}{k_{2}} \\[3ex]
 \dfrac{1}{Pr}&=\dfrac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}       &   A&=\dfrac{b}{a}\\[3ex]
S_{c}&=\dfrac{\nu}{D_{B}}   &   \dfrac{1}{k_{1}}&=\dfrac{\mu \phi}{k'}\\[3ex]
 S_{r}&=\dfrac{D_{m}\,k_{T}\,\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)}{\alpha_{m}\,C_{p}\,C_{s}\,\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)}      &   D_{f}&=\dfrac{D_{m}\,k_{T}\,\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)}{\alpha_{m}\,C_{p}\,C_{s}\,\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Removing `\begin{equation}`, `\end{equation}` environment and changing `align*` to `align` fixes everything.

[image]

If you want them singularly vertical:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\large

\begin{align}
 \lambda=\dfrac{Gr_{x}}{R_{e}^2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \widetilde{N}=\dfrac{Gr_{x}^{\ast}}{Gr_{x}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 Gr_{x}=\dfrac{g\beta_{T}\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)x^{3}}{\nu^{2}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 Gr_{x}^{\ast}=\dfrac{g\beta_{C}\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)x^{3}}{\nu^{2}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 M^{2}=\dfrac{\sigma\,B_{0}^{2}}{a\,\rho\, x^{n-1}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 Nr=\dfrac{16\sigma^{\ast}}{3k^{\ast}}\,\dfrac{T^{3}_{\infty}}{k_{2}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \dfrac{1}{Pr}=\dfrac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 A=\dfrac{b}{a}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 S_{c}=\dfrac{\nu}{D_{B}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \dfrac{1}{k_{1}}=\dfrac{\mu \phi}{k'}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 S_{r}=\dfrac{D_{m}\,k_{T}\,\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)}{\alpha_{m}\,C_{p}\,C_{s}\,\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)}     
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 D_{f}=\dfrac{D_{m}\,k_{T}\,\left(T_{w}-T_{\infty}\right)}{\alpha_{m}\,C_{p}\,C_{s}\,\left(C_{w}-C_{\infty}\right)}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sequential `align` environments with no alignment point is a bad style. That's what  `gather` is for.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very new to LaTeX @campa :(